# Decorators should not have side effects?

Tags: python, django, decorator

Editing because the initial code was confusing.

I would assume these two things to be same,

```
#I would use either of these
#Option 1
def bar(*args):
    pass
foo = deco(bar)

#Option2
@deco
def foo(*args):
    pass
```

However if the decorators `deco` has side effects, this is not guaranteed. In particular, this was my expectation form a decorator(no side effect), and I came across one with side effect and was bitten by it,

```
#Option1
def bar(*args):
    pass
foo = register.filter(bar)

#Option 2
@register.filter
def foo(val, arg):
    pass
```

So is my expectation wrong, or is Django being inconsistent with the best practices?

Comment: A thread from 2004 by Jim Hugunin seems to think so. http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2004-April/044133.html

Comment: A Question was asked below, so adding that, bar is another callable.

Comment: your examples make no sense, because you throw away the foo you define. you'd use deco to decorate foo, so you get a new foo.

Comment: hop: Ok edited code to explain things better.

Comment: I need access to both decorated and undecorated function later, and hence teh Option 1 code.

Comment: This question makes no sense. @deco is just syntactic sugar for foo = deco(foo); they are identical. What is your actual problem? What is the actual side effect that is bothering you? There are some tricks to writing well-behaved decorators (this is some of what Jim Hugunin is talking about), but that has nothing to do with any of your code examples above; you don't even show the code of your decorators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, these both are exactly the same:

```
def foo(*args):
    pass
foo = deco(foo)

@deco
def foo(*args):
    pass
```

If you want to decorate `bar` and call it `foo`, `foo = deco(bar)` is the right way. It says: "decorate this previously defined thing called `bar` and call it `foo`". The point of the decorator syntax is to state the wrapping function before the definition, not to rename it.

Unless you need to use `bar` later, there is no reason to call the undecorated function with a different name. By doing this you lose precisely the ability to use the decorator syntax sugar.

`deco` doesn't need to be a function. It can be an object with a `__call__` method, which is useful precisely to encapsulate side effects.

Comment: @roberto: exactly. My quwstion is, should it also be exactly the same as `foo = deco(bar)`

Comment: What the heck is `bar`?  Decorator `deco` wraps method `foo`, and is equivalent exactly to `foo = deco(foo)`.  Why do you keep asking about `foo = deco(bar)`?  Perhaps this misconception of yours is the fundamental issue.

Comment: bar is another callable. I want to bind the retirn value of deco(bar) to foo.

Answer (score 0):

Your examples do not express the same things in every case! Why do you insist on using bar?

Take your first example:

```
#Option 1
def bar(*args):
    pass
foo = deco(bar)

#Option2
@deco
def foo(*args):
    pass
```

Option 1 does (literally)

```
foo = deco(bar)
```

but Option 2 is the equivalent of

```
foo = deco(foo)
```

Can't you see the difference there?

So, in short, yes: your assumption and your expectations are wrong.

If you need the undecorated version of your function, as well as the decorated one, just save it beforehand:

```
def foo(*args):
    pass
bar = foo
foo = deco(foo)
```

Comment: > Why do you insist on using bar? 

Because I need access to both decorated and undecorated function.

My assumptions are (obviously) wrong. But why is my expectation that it be side-effect free wrong?

Comment: why would you restrict yourself with such an arbitrary rule?

Comment: does Library().register() even do something to func, except registering it? foo should be the same before and after...

Comment: look at template/defaultfilters.py: you don't even have to use the return value of register.filter()!